# Number guessing game does not recognize correct answer after 1st guess

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

If you do not guess the number correctly on the first try, the program will run until you run out of guesses regardless if you guessed the correct number. Is there a problem with my while loop or if statements?

```
while True:
    try:
        Guessed_number = int(raw_input("What is your guess? \n"))
    except ValueError: 
        print("Sorry, that is not a valid guess. Please guess again.")
        continue
    else:
        break 
def Number_guesser(Guessed_number):
    guesses= 3
    while guesses > 0: 

    if Random_number == Guessed_number:
        print "Congratualations! You won :)" 
        break

    elif Guessed_number > Random_number:
        print "You guessed higher than the number. Try again! \n"
        print Random_number
        Guessed_number= raw_input()
        guesses= guesses-1 

    elif Guessed_number < Random_number:
        print "You guessed lower than the number. Try again! \n"
        Guessed_number= raw_input() 
        guesses= guesses-1

    if guesses == 3:
        print "You have 3 guesses left!" 

    elif guesses == 2:
        print "You have 2 guesses left!"

    elif guesses == 1:
        print "You have 1 guess left!"

    elif guesses == 0:
        print "You ran out of guesses :( \n The correct answer was........*drum roll*" 
        print Random_number
print Number_guesser(Guessed_number)`
```

Comment: Your indentation is definitely incorrect (or the way you pasted it), which is critical for python program.

Comment: First off, you are redefining `guesses` to be 3 every time the function Number_guesser is called.  This looks like it is not your intention based on the logic further down in the function.

Next, you get more input within the `Number_guesser` function, but you only do that one time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my raw_input needed to be an integer every time I prompted the player to guess again.

```
Guessed_number= int(raw_input())
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the problem! There's quite a bit that can be done to clean up your code, however. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/d5198882e5d87dcb434a) for some other ideas.